# Newbee Terminal adding Flask to Path

Tags: python, flask, terminal

I downloaded 'FLASK' recently and it gave me this message "Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location."

Tried changing my path

"echo $PATH
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
" to 
"PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$P$"

it's still not working, did I miss a step or not add it correctly?

steps to download flask:

download flask using "sudo easy_install pip" then "pip install flask

Comment: Did you have python installed and working before this? Is is MacOS?

Comment: can you share the steps how you installed flask?

Comment: yes python worked perfectly and it still works

Comment: download flask  using "sudo easy_install pip" then "pip install flask"